# 0x00 and char arrays

Tags: c++, char

Why do char arrays stop right before a 0x00 byte is detected and how can this problem be avoided (perhaps by using another datatype (which one and why) or a "trick" with char)?

For example in the following code, the output is "a" only, the other bytes are not displayed:

```
unsigned char cbuffer[]={0x61,0x00,0x62,0x63,0x0};
std::string sbuffer=reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cbuffer);

cout << sbuffer << endl;
```

Similarly in the following code, the output is "ab":

```
unsigned char cbuffer[]={0x61,0x62,0x00,0x63,0x0};
std::string sbuffer=reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cbuffer);
```

Straightforward and effective workarounds to the problem (where 0x00 is kept in the array as a normal byte) would be appreciated.

Comment: Ummm.  Because strings in C are arrays of char terminated with a zero byte?

Comment: std::vector with overloaded `operator << (ostream&, const vector<char>&)`.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Not necessarily.  It's not uncommon to not use trailing zeros.  The language itself only requires it for string _literals_.  The libraries may also require it, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's common in C to pass around strings as pointers to null-terminated `char` arrays.  null is represented by `0x00`.  To make conversion easy, the `std::string` is constructable from a pointer to a null-terminated char array, which is what is happening with your code.  But when it finds the null, it thinks that's the end of the string.  If you `cout` a char array directly, you'll find it makes the same assumption, because they have no other way to determine the end of a string pointed to by a `char*`.  (They could theoretically tell the length in your case, if they understood `char (&)[]`, but almost nothing in the standard library does sadly).

The intended workarounds are to use this constructor instead:

```
int len = sizeof(cbuffer)/sizeof(cbuffer[0]);
std::string sbuffer(cbuffer, len); //5 characters in cbuffer, 1 byte each
```

or

```
int len = sizeof(cbuffer)/sizeof(cbuffer[0]);
std::cout.write(cbuffer, len); //5 characters in buffer, 1 byte each
```

However, you have to be careful with `sizeof(cbuffer)`.  If `cbuffer` is a `char*` (pointer) instead of a `char(&)[]` (array), then `sizeof(ptr)` will return the wrong value, and there is no way to get the correct length at that point, if the string is not null-terminated.

Comment: This is good except for not advocating usign `sizeof` to determine the buffer length.

Comment: @MarkB: I actually had that at first, but then removed it, because of the common "why does sizeof(ptr) return 4, I have 10 letters!".  I'll edit the answer to describe the pros and cons.

Comment: @curiousguy: What?  Do you think my terminology/spelling is incorrect?

Comment: @Mooing Duck.  Your spelling is incorrect.  NULL is a pointer and NUL is a character.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Wikipedia disagrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character.  NULL is the name of the character.  It's commonly abbreviated as NUL however.

Comment: @MooingDuck "_Do you think my terminology/spelling is incorrect?_" Yes, indeed. "_Wikipedia disagrees_" does not: "The null character (also null terminator), abbreviated NUL," it's null, not NULL.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: I will concede that I misunderstood that NULL is a pointer, and null a concept.  However, laughing at a citation seems (1) rude, (2) silly considering you did not cite anything at all.

Comment: You should divide by sizeof(cbuffer[0]). Who knows when somebody else (a maintainer with an axe) will switche the underlying type to wchar_t and std::wstring.

Comment: @curiousguy: NULL may be a name for the ASCII character, but it's also a standard C and C++ macro that expands to a null pointer constant.  I've edited the answer, changing "NULL-terminated" to the less confusing "null-terminated".

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oddly, your edit was at least 16 minutes after I made the exact same edit

Comment: Yes, that's odd.  The edit history shows us both changing NULL to null.  (I also added the phrase "string pointed to by a".)

Answer (score 2):

char arrays don't do anything

The C string functions use 0 to mark the end of a string.
std::cout is overloaded for char arrays to print them as 'c' strings, if you want to print individual values you need to loop over the values, you might also want to output them as std::hex

In this case you are creating a std::String from a 'c' char array so the ctor of the std::string assumes that 'c' strings end at '0'. Since it's only passed an address in memory how else can it know where the string ends?

ps. If you want to store an array of bytes you should probably be using std::vector

Comment: he doesn't `cout` a char array, he `cout`s a `std::string` object, which doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    unsigned char cbuffer[]={0x61,0x62,0x00,0x63,0x0};

    // Here s1 is treating the cBuffer as a C-String
    // Thus it will only read upto the first '\0' character
    std::string s1(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cbuffer));
    std::cout << s1 << "\n";

    // Here s2 is treating the cBuffer as an array.
    // It reads the specified length into the string.
    std::string s2(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cbuffer), sizeof(cbuffer)/sizeof(cbuffer[0]));

    // Note: How std::cout prints the '\0' character may leave it empty. 
    std::cout << s2 << "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 0x00 byte is used as a sentinel to mark the end of the string in C. The entire array however remains in memory. You can use an alternate constructor for `std::string` if you want the string to contain the entire character array. But printing that string would still give you only "ab". This decision to represent C strings in this manner is one of those [arbitrary](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2010365) decisions that we are stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

0x00 is a non print character, 0..0x20, are all non print `char`s although some serve as line breaks. 0x00 serves to terminate a string.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to be substituted (and printed) for 0x00 in the resulting string?

The constructor is responsible for conversion of char[] into a string.
As others pointed out, you must use different constructor. The code below is working for me, but it is not very roboust. The first parameter must be a pointer to the array (you are free to use safer casting) and the second parameter is the length of the array (you are free to calculate this in a more
sophisticated way).

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  unsigned char cbuffer[]={0x61,0x00,0x62,0x63,0x00};
  std::string sbuffer((char *)cbuffer,5);
  std::cout << sbuffer << std::endl;
}
```